# Create complex custom legend using lines/markers as 'floats' inline in text

Tags: matplotlib

### Problem

I want to create a complex custom legend in which the line-/marker-style appears inline in a text (like a float, e.g. an inline equation, in LaTeX). However, I have no idea how to do this elegantly.

### Desired output

[image]

### Desired code

My ideal code for typical line would look something like:

```py
h2 = ax.plot(..., marker='o', color='tab:green')
h4 = ax.plot(..., marker='o', color='tab:blue')
h8 = ax.plot(..., marker='o', color='tab:purple')
h16 = ax.plot(..., marker='o', color='tab:red')

ax.text(0, 1, ' '.join([
    'depth', 
    create_float(h2), '(2)', 
    create_float(h4), '(4)', 
    create_float(h8), '(8)', 
    create_float(h16), '(16)'])
```

### Current code

My disappointing code for the moment is:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.text(0, -1, 'width: 2', ha='left', va='center')

x = 0
ax.text(x, 0, 'depth:', ha='left', va='center')
x += 0.2
ax.plot(x, 0, marker='o', color='tab:green')
x += 0.08
ax.text(x, 0, '(2)', ha='center', va='center')
x += 0.08
ax.plot(x, 0, marker='o', color='tab:blue')
x += 0.08
ax.text(x, 0, '(4)', ha='center', va='center')
x += 0.08
ax.plot(x, 0, marker='o', color='tab:purple')
x += 0.08
ax.text(x, 0, '(8)', ha='center', va='center')
x += 0.08
ax.plot(x, 0, marker='o', color='tab:red')
x += 0.08
ax.text(x, 0, '(16)', ha='center', va='center')

x = 0
ax.text(x, 1, 'shuffle:', ha='left', va='center')
x += 0.2
ax.plot(x, 1, marker='s', color='k')
x += 0.1
ax.text(x, 1, "(yes)", ha='center', va='center')
x += 0.1
ax.plot(x, 1, marker='o', color='k')
x += 0.1
ax.text(x, 1, "(no)", ha='center', va='center')

x = 0
ax.text(x, 2, r'probability:', ha='left', va='center')
x += 0.31
ax.plot(x, 2, marker='o', color='k', fillstyle='full')
x += 0.16
ax.text(x, 2, "(random)", ha='center', va='center')
x += 0.16
ax.plot(x, 2, marker='o', color='k', fillstyle='none')
x += 0.16
ax.text(x, 2, "(constant)", ha='center', va='center')

ax.set_xlim([-0.2, 1.5])
ax.set_ylim([-2.2, 4.2])

plt.savefig('plot.png')
plt.close()
```

Comment: `plt.legend()` has options handles and ncol. Have you tried them?

Comment: Hi @rpoleski . `legend` can indeed do quite a bit. But what I want is arguably beyond the scope of legend: I want the put text before any handle, and I don't want to be limited to square 'matrices': the number of handles per row varies.